# Conflicting Dataclasses is there any workaround?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to create a sandbox environment using two matching databases held on different servers. What I am trying to is pass data in between but only when an Administrator gives the 'Ok'. Now the coding behind this is fine, I have a solution for how I am going to implement this but what I am struggling to do is have two dataclasses both referencing the different databases but with matching tables?

When I attempt to pull any form of data through LINQ I get the error that the **member is already defined more than once.**

Is there any way of having matching dataclasses (but point to different servers), without having to change the table names?

Comment: How are you generating the Dataclasses? Could you generate in separate namespaces?

Comment: The Dataclasses are automatically being generated by LINQ????? Can you explain further?

Comment: FYI, Linq-to-sql is separate from linq itself - you can use LINQ with any old collection of objects, not just databases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the mapping between your classes and the database schema is *exactly* the same across the two databases, you could have **just one set of classes** and simply initialize two data contexts with **different connection strings** to access the databases.

Here's an example using LINQ to SQL:

```
var leftConnString = "Data Source=LeftServer;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase";
var rightConnString = "Data Source=RightServer;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase";

using (var leftContext = new DataContext(leftConnString))
{
    using (var rightContext = new DataContext(rightConnString))
    {
        // Retrieve entities from 'leftContext'
        // and persist them in 'rightContext'
    }
}
```